# Wordpress - How to add a blog template to a page using a blank theme

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm loading a front-end site onto Wordpress using html5 blank child theme. The client has asked me to add a blog page to the site. I've created the page and added it to the header.php.

I'm not sure why but my page, regardless of whether I update it or not, has this comment showing all the time -

[image: Blog page]

I'v tried searching on google but I can't find anything to suggest why this comment stays here all the time. How do I build the blog template - is there a .php file in the parent theme that I have to replicate? Or do I use a plugin? It doesn't need to be anything more than a bog standard wordpress blog page so they can add some posts from time to time.

Here's what I have in my header -

**header.php**

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(4); ?>#particle-slider">Home</a>
            <a href="#what">What we do</a>
            <a href="#who">Who we are</a>
            <a href="#partners">Who we work with</a>
            <a href="#contact">Say hello</a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(70); ?>">Blog</a>
        </nav>
    <!-- script type="text/javascript"></script -->
    </header>
```

I've looked at Appearances>Menu but the menu is not letting me update for some reason. Is there a hidden error somewhere I'm missing? An assistance appreciated.

Comment: There are a whole lot of things wrong here. You need to see the codex mate.

Comment: @shazyriver Thanks. Can you at least give me a clue? You've basically stated what I already know.

Comment: Template hierarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Using wordpress menu https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 0):

The "You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts." message comes from having that particular page set as your "Posts page" in the Settings > Reading edit screen.

In that case your theme's index.php file will be used for displaying that page (or home.php). More on that in the codex. https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen

And as @shazyriver pointed out you should familiarize yourself with the WordPress Navigation Menus codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus and the Template Hierarchy.

Comment: This is very confusing, can't believe there isn't just a set template for a blog page to drop in. How do I even style the page?

Comment: Your current menu isn't using the wp_nav_menu function which outputs the markup for menus created under the Appearance > Menus section in the Dashboard.

index.php is the fallback for all templates. It generally consists of a basic WordPress loop. As noted in the template hierarchy if you're Reading Settings has Posts Page set that page first looks for home.php then index.php.

If you wanted to build a custom template you would not select that page as the Posts page in the Reading Settings area.